# How to Toggel Read-More from Button with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this text, which i want to toggle with Jquery.

```
<div class="section-right">
    <h1>
         about us
    </h1>
    <h2>
        real fitness depends on excercise.
    </h2>
    <div class="detail-text" data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
        <p class="more">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        </p>
    </div>
    <button class="myButton readMore">
        <span>
            More About
        </span>
        <div><img src="assets/images/rightArrow.png" alt="arrow"></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

that `more` class in `p` tag is `display: hidden`. i am cropping text to limited number of of words with jquery.

```
// Readmore Text
var showChar = 100;
$('.more').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + "..." + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }
});

$(".readMore").click(function () {
    // $(this).prev('.detail-text p').slideToggle(500);
    // $(this).prev('.detail-text p').toggleClass('more');
});
```

My logic is to toggle `more` class of `readmore` button sibling.
How can i toggle above text with button which is not direct sibling?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for you:

```js
// Readmore Text
var showChar = 100;
$('.more').each(function () {
 var content = $(this).html();

 if (content.length > showChar) {
  var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
  var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

  var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + "..." + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent">' + h + '<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
  $(this).html(html);
 }
});

$(".readMore").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.detail-text').children('p').toggleClass('more');
});
```

```css
p span.moreellipses{
 display: none;
}
p.more span.moreellipses{
 display: inline;
}
.more span.morecontent{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-right">
 <h1>
  about us
 </h1>
 <h2>
  real fitness depends on excercise.
 </h2>
 <div class="detail-text" data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
  <p class="more">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </p>
 </div>
 <button class="myButton readMore">
  <span>
   More About
  </span>
  <div><img src="assets/images/rightArrow.png" alt="arrow"></div>
 </button>
</div>
```